# ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender

Tags: error, transfer

Token was created under ERC223.  Every transfer that I have done received:
ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender.

Please help to check and see what I need to do correct this?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x42a3f4746279e37484fef91b2f41d81c9e48583e411c4a00df9cbc47dc1e8881

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning, Etherscan is looking for the `Transfer(sender,recipient,amount)` event and it can't find it because ERC223 uses slightly different event `Transfer(sender,recipient,amount,data)`.

It shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps a wallet that is not aware of ERC223 tokens will not update the balance correctly, but the balance should be correct on the blockchain.